# LDAP search filter for users with group membership in group name (but not whole path)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I did my research before asking this but it came to nothing :-(

I'm trying to create an LDAP filter. The goal is to get users (objectClass=person in this case) which are members of a specific group. The thing is, the group might for various purposes be moved around in our AD so the complete path/search base is not given, but the group name is -it will remain unchanged.

So I tried something like:

`(&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=(objectcategory=group)(name=MYADGROUPNAME)))`

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

TIA

Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the filter syntax is wrong (but the intention is correct), you can't pass a filter as the value of another filter, instead you need to run two distinct search queries, the result of the first one being used to expand the filter of the second one.

- The `memberOf` attribute holds a collection of the distinguished name(s) of the group(s) to which the object belongs, so in order to get users of a specific group, the filter in the final query should look like :

  ```
  (&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=<groupDN>))
  ```
- This implies a prior query to grab the group DN. If the base is not given, set the search scope to `subtree` and the search base to a parent dn common to all user groups (eg. `ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com`). For the group filter, you need to specify a unique identifier, eg. assuming the object name (`cn` attribute) is unique in that scope/objectcategory :

  ```
  (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=MYADGROUPNAME))
  ```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely in the right direction, with ```(&(objectcategory=group)(cn=MYADGROUPNAME))``` I can already get the group I need without the full path.


My problem is basically that this is not my code; it's a specific product I'm using, and there's only one place for a filter. See here:


https://drive.google.com/file/d/11VXtUqFFffpSD_-4g_rcuvXkFTUq1YVV/view?invite=CMfyppIC&ts=635939b0


That's why I'm trying to do the equivalent of an SQL join.


Is this somehow possible?

Comment: No you can't do it this way with a single query. Though that product might offer different strategies to do the same thing so I suggest you open another question which better focuses on that thing, and which tool is it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll contact the manufacturer although I'm not very optimistic.